# GET Request to JSON API Occasionally Returns a Blank Response

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have a scraper in Python that is requesting the contents of the JSON found at:
`https://www.saltybet.com/state.json`

Code:

```
import requests
import time


class SaltyJson():
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://www.saltybet.com/state.json"
        self.session = requests.Session()

    def get_json(self):
        try:
            self.response = self.session.get(self.url,
                                             headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0", "Accept": "application/json"})
            if self.response.status_code != 200:
                time.sleep(1)
                self.get_json()
            else:
                return self.response.json()
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.get_json()
        except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.get_json()
```

The GET request works initially, but usually after a few hours, I will receive a `requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error. It appears that I am receiving an empty response (i.e. the `self.response.json()` returns `None` ). This occurs even when a 200 server status code is returned.

This issue has been challenging as it is sporadic in nature, and the majority of cases I've seen dealing with this error on SO are either due to the JSON being invalid, the User-Agent / Accept header is missing, the server giving an error status code. In my case, my requests work 99% of the time, but I keep receiving this occasional blank response, even when the returned server status code indicates a successful response (200).

I have looked up that JSONDecodeError, and my understanding is that if it errors on `char 0` then either the entire JSON is invalid or it is a blank response. If I handle the JSONDecodeError with the except clause, it appears that the JSON is returning None. Trying to access a value from the JSON dict, `self.json_dict["remaining"]` , returns `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` . My debugger said the json_dict was `{NoneType}`, which I interpreted as the entire dict was None, and that this wasn't an issue with a null key/value.

Things I tried:

1. Adding exponential backoff in case this was a form of server rate limiting
2. Adding a check for server status code 200
3. Checking if number of json keys matches expected output (`len(list(self.response.json().keys())) == 8`)

One thing I noticed about the URL is that the content-type header is text/html, not application/json. Even with my GET request having the `"Accept":"application/json"` header, it seems that the content-type of the response is still `text/html`. Looking at the javascript code for the website, the content type is specified to be application/json...

```
        url: "../state.json"  + "?t=" + ms,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

My two questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my GET request, possibly with the passed headers, causing this occasional blank response? Is this issue possibly related to the content-type being `text/html`, even though the contents should only be valid JSON?
2. Assuming this is a blank/empty response, are there additional checks I need to add to my code besides checking the server status code?

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) Maybe the server occasionally produces a blank response because of some server error (i.e. there is no problem with your request). 2) For debugging, it might be helpful to log `self.response.text` so that you know what exactly you get (rather than guessing based on the decoder error).

Answer (score 0):

*Short version:*

1. The request itself is okay* (see comments below). requests' json() can load a properly utf-8 encoded string that can be loaded with json.loads() as well.
2. Use try/except since you don't know what you got is json-decodable. Currently you're mixing try/except for two different operations (request and json-decode)

I think the bottom line is a slight misunderstanding:

You can never rely on server responses to be as you expect or rather like them to be. In the best case, they *should* work as expected, but this isn't even the case for the most professionally set-up sites.

This goes certainly for status codes. A server *may* and in many cases *should* return status codes that tell you what's going on. It doesn't mean it has to and even if it does, sometimes that just doesn't mean you get what you expect. **Status code 200 does not mean *success* in regards to what you wanted, but to what the server deems a success.**

*What could be* happening here is for instance an internal error (api cannot access the data) but the server doesn't relay that information (either on purpose or the api doesn't check data before it returns a response).

Practically speaking, you can try it out for yourself:

```
>>> import requests
>>> x = requests.models.Response()
>>> x._content = b'{}'
>>> x.json()
{}
```

but:

```
>>> x._content = {}
>>> x.json()
...
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
...
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

and the same if the response body is empty (including empty string):

```
>>> import requests
>>> x = requests.models.Response()
>>> x.json()
...
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
...
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

A non-empty string would yield you a TypeError unless it is properly UTF-8 encoded.

**Regarding *NoneType*.**
I can't see how this could be the direct outcome of response.json() unless there is some nifty bug in the json decoder. response.json() will either raise an Exception or return a valid object (which *may or may not* contain they key you're trying to access). I can only assume you got this by not using recursive calls in the except block (see comment below). If this was the case, you end up returning nothing which is nothing so NoneType. You can avoid this always returning *something*.

**On a side-note,** you may want to rethink the way this code deals with exceptions:

```
    except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
        time.sleep(1)
        self.get_json()
```

While it may work, you can run into a **RecursionError** (maximum recursion depth exceeded). It doesn't take that many more lines to separate handling the error from trying another request. This also looks like you're somewhat soft-hammering the server with requests, no matter what. A simple error counter and a threshold after which your script stops trying to get the response it doesn't get would probably be nice.

At the very least you'd want to:

```
try:
    return self.response.json()
except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError:
    # what to do now
```

But I'd refactor the code to something like this:

Separate

1. request / except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
2. json() / except requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError

And from the outside handle the repeated calls to get_json()